# Find the maximum allowable bending moment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, material-science, continuum-mechanics

A rolled steel universal I-section beam with a serial size of $406\times178$ has a mass of $60$kg/m. What is the maximum safe allowable bending moment this beam can sustain,given that the maximum allowable bending stress in tension and compression must not exceed $165$N/mm$^2$.

I have this problem and I have no Idea to solve this. Please kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: Hi Flip, and welcome to physics stack exchange.  As this appears to be a homework problem, you need to describe what steps you have taken to solve this by yourself.  What lectures have you attended on this subject, what textbooks are you using, and what relevant information do these provide?

Comment: Also please do not use specialist terminology like "serial size".  Also you might like to point out to your teacher that the SI unit of stress is the pascal, and the relevant unit here is the MPa.  Sorry to be a bit pedantic!